# Добавление плагина в меню WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Как выводить настройки плагина в меню(для внесения настроек ключей к API), и из скрипта обращаться к этим параметрам, но быстрым поиском я не нашел ничего более-менее описывающего внесение настроек плагина в меню, и как потом к этим параметрам обращаться из самого скрипта, подскажите пожалуйста что почитать/где посмотреть на эту тему. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно ознакомится с Settings API https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API. Там много чего описано, от создания страницы, до создание полей, обработки ошибок и т.д.

Пример создания пункта меню:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );
function register_my_custom_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page( 
        'custom menu title', 'custom menu', 'manage_options', 'custompage', 'my_custom_menu_page', plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ), 6 
    ); 
}

function my_custom_menu_page(){
    echo "Код страницы.";   
}
```

https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_menu_page

Так же неплохой пример работы с Settings API: https://wp-kama.ru/id_3773/api-optsiy-nastroek.html