# Как создать кастомное поле админ-панели wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста, как создавать свои собственные разделы в админ панели wordpress? Или посоветуйте источники, которые хорошо описывают эту тему.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Добавление плагина в меню WordPress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1080095/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-wordpress)

Comment: Чтобы нечто оказалось "в меню" (любом) должна быть создана сущность, на которую будет ссылаться этот пункт. И вот когда создаются такие сущности - пункты в меню могут появиться "сами" (напр когда создаются кастомные типы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно ознакомится с Settings API https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API. Там много чего описано, от создания страницы, до создание полей, обработки ошибок и т.д.

Пример создания пункта меню:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );
function register_my_custom_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page( 
        'custom menu title', 'custom menu', 'manage_options', 'custompage', 'my_custom_menu_page', plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ), 6 
    ); 
}

function my_custom_menu_page(){
    echo "Код страницы.";   
}
```

https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_menu_page

Так же неплохой пример работы с Settings API: https://wp-kama.ru/id_3773/api-optsiy-nastroek.html